# How do I stop the scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to grab 3 strings from the user.

The issue I'm running into at the moment is that the scanner never ends/never stores the first user input value? With the limited amount of research I've done so far it appears that the scanner method has some intricacies that lie far beyond the cover.

My current code is below, followed by the complete method. Any sort of explanation would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Code pertaining to question:

```
 //prompt user for array values by row
        System.out.println("Enter matrix values by row: ");
        userInput[0] = in.nextLine();
        userInput[1] = in.nextLine();
        userInput[2] = in.nextLine();
```

Complete method:

```
public static double[][] setArray()
{

    //initiate variables
    String stringValue = "";
    double doubleValue = 0;

    //instantiate string array for user input values
    String[] userInput =  new String[3];
    //instantiate return array
    double[][] array = new double[3][4];

    //prompt user for array values by row
    System.out.println("Enter matrix values by row: ");
    userInput[0] = in.nextLine();
    userInput[1] = in.nextLine();
    userInput[2] = in.nextLine();

    //stop each scanner



    int valueCounter = 0;

    for(int eachString = 0; eachString < 3; eachString++)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < userInput[eachString].length(); index++)
        {

            //exception handling
            //if string does not contain a space, period, or valid digit
            while(userInput[eachString].charAt(index) != ' ' 
                    && userInput[eachString].charAt(index) < '0' 
                    && userInput[eachString].charAt(index) > '9'
                    && userInput[eachString].charAt(index) != '.')
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Digits must be in integer"
                        + " or double form. (i.e. 4  5.0  2.3  9)");  
                System.out.println("Re-enter given matrix value");
                userInput[eachString] = in.nextLine();
            }
        }

        //given string is valid at this point//

        //for each index in string value
        for(int eachIndex = 0; eachIndex < userInput[eachString].length(); eachIndex++)
        {

            //while value != ' '... += string... if value == ' ' stop loop
            while(userInput[eachString].charAt(eachIndex) != ' ')
            {

                stringValue += userInput[eachString].charAt(eachIndex);

            }

            doubleValue = Double.valueOf(stringValue);
            array[eachString][valueCounter] = doubleValue;
            valueCounter++;//array[0-2][0-3 (valueCounter)]
            stringValue = "";//clear string

        }

    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just want to break up the scanner to read 1 number at a time and then ask for the second number and then read it in and then ask for the third number.

Or you could have them provide the 3 numbers divided by a space or something and read it in as a string and split the string per each space and parse to each userInput.

I would so the latter, it would look something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter matrix values by row: ");
    String temp = in.nextLine();
    String[] tempArray = temp.split("\\s+");
    userInput[0] = tempArray[0];
    userInput[1] = tempArray[1];
    userInput[2] = tempArray[2];
```

Obviously error checking needs to happen. But this should work for you.